# Prge_replace is not working properly in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace the below string

```
`$test_numbers_4 = '\\;\\3;4;5';
```

to

`3,4,5`

Here is my code

```
$test_numbers_4 = '\\;\\3;4;5';
printf( "<h4>Task 4:</h4>\n" ); 
$str = preg_replace('/\s{0,}/', '', $test_numbers_4); 
$str1 = preg_replace('/\\\\\\|;\\\\/', ',', $str); 
$array = explode(',', $str1);
$res=implode( ',', $array) ;
echo $res;
```

**Output**: `3,4,5`

```
Edit:
```

I have a string like this `$string =\\,\\2,7,-3,5,-2`  if string is like this when i run the file i would like to show error message saying that `negative numbers -3,-2 not allowed.`

But it's not giving me the result what I expected

Can anyone help me what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to throw away things that are not numbers or `;`, in which case you can do that with this code. It uses `preg_replace` to remove unwanted characters then `preg_split` to split into an array on `;`, with the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to ensure no empty values in the array.

```
$test_numbers_4 = '\\;\\3;4;5';
$str = preg_replace('/[^\d;]/', '', $test_numbers_4); 
$array = preg_split('/;/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$res=implode(',', $array) ;
echo $res;
```

Output:

```
3,4,5
```

If you specifically want to just remove spaces and double backslashes, then use this preg_replace:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\\\\|\s+/', '', $test_numbers_4);
```

Comment: Yup its working and i have one more doubt similart to this can i ask

Comment: If it's part of the same question then just edit your question. If not, you should ask a new question.

Comment: its a part of question only about preg_replace only

Comment: Go for it then! :)

Comment: i have string like this $string =\\,\\ 2,7,-3,5,-2 if it is like this i would throw error message when i run the file saying that negative numbers -3,-2 not allowed

Comment: i have edited my question can you please check and help me out with that

Comment: The new string uses `,` as the delimiter not `;`?

Comment: Yes it is comma (,) not semicolon (;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179262/discussion-between-nick-and-suresh).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this steps to get what you need-

1. Remove every character that is non-digit using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
2. separate every character using [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
3. implode it with comma using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/IKoYt